# Baye's Rule Question Help

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

The following are data regarding a mammorgram:

- In the absence of any special information, the probability that a
  woman (of the age and health status of this patient) has breast
  cancer is 1%.
- If the patient has breast cancer, the probability that the
  radiologist will correctly diagnose it is 80%.
- If the patient has a benign lesion (no breast cancer), the
  probability that the radiologist will incorrectly diagnose it as
  cancer is 10%.

What is the probability that a patient with a  positive mammogram actually has breast cancer?

Let $B$ indicate breast cancer and $D$ indicate a correct diagnosis. Then $P(B) = .01, \ P(\neg B) =  .99, \ P(D|B) = .8, \ P(\neg D | B) = .2, \ P(\neg D | \neg B) = .1, \ P(D | \neg B) = .9$

From Baye's Rule:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P(B|D) &=  P(D|B)\times P(B) /  \big [ P(D|B)\times P(B) + P(D|\neg B) \times P(\neg B)\big] \\
&= .8 \times .01 / [.8 \times .01 + .9 \times .99] \\
&= .039
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

But my textbook (Rice, Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis 3e, p. 23) says the answer is .075. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey! I answered that question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4789368/1237483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define $D$ to be a **correct** diagnosis.  That is not the same as a **positive** diagnosis.

So, let's use $P$ for Positive diagnosis.

Now you want to find $P(B|P)$.

You 'still' have:

$P(P|B)=.8$ and $P(\neg P|B)=.2$

But the crucial difference is:

$P(P|\neg B)=.1$ and $P(\neg P|\neg B)=.9$

OK, so try that.