# The probability of having HIV for someone who tests positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Assume one person out of 10,000 is infected with HIV, and there is a test in which 2.5%
of all people test positive for the virus although they do not really have it. If you test
negative on this test, then you definitely do not have HIV. Let H be the event of having
HIV and T be the event of testing positive. Find the following.

(a) Pr(T|H), the probability of testing positive for someone with HIV.

(b) Pr(H ∩ T), the probability of having HIV and testing positive.

(c) Pr(T|H'), the probability of testing positive for someone without HIV.

(d) Pr(H'∩ T), the probability of not having HIV and testing positive.

(e) Pr(T), the probability of testing positive.

(f) Pr(H|T), the probability of having HIV for someone who tests positive.

I already get Pr(H) = 0.0001, Pr(H') = 0.9999 ,Pr(T|H')= 0.025 ,
Pr(H|T)= 0.0395 -Calcaluted with bayes theorem
Now the question is how to do part (b) , part (d), and part (e)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: what does "if you test negative on the test then you definitely don't have HIV" translate to in terms of a probability?

Comment: The question seems to be poorly worded:  Clarification requested: Are we to assume that in a group of exactly $(10000)$ people, exactly $(1)$ of whom has HIV, that if all $(10000)$ are tested, then the $(1)$ who has HIV will test positive, and $(249)$ of the other  $(9999)$ will also test positive?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You and I just approached the same question from different directions.  Apparently, we are both waiting for the OP (i.e. original poster) to clarify the problem.

Comment: @user2661923 2.5% of 9999  is about 250 people not 2499.

Comment: $P(H \cap T)=P(T|H)P(H)$ is one option. There are more.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Good catch, thanks - I edited my comment/question.

Comment: $P(T) = P(T|H)P(H) + P(T|H')P(H')$ or other such facts are options.

Comment: Thanks btw. I have another question. How to get P(T | H)?

Comment: This only works if you test people at random. You don’t. You test people who are at higher risk than average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

p:  **HIV prevalance (ignoring prior risk factors)**
v:  **test sensitivity**
f:  **test specificity**
H:  HIV-positive
H':  HIV-negative
+:  Positive test result
-:  Negative test result

We are given that \begin{align}p&=0.0001,\\1-f=0.025,\text{ i.e., }f&=0.975\\v&=1.\end{align}

Referring to the above probability tree and given values,

> (a) Pr(T|H)

$P(T|H)=v$

> (b) Pr(H ∩ T)

$P(H ∩ T)=pv$

> (d) Pr(H'T)

$P(H'∩ T)=(1-p)(1-f)$

> (e) P(T)

$P(T)=P(H∩T)+P(H'∩T)$

> (f) Pr(H|T)
>
> Pr(H|T)= 0.0395

\begin{aligned}P(H|T)&=\frac{P(H∩T)}{P(H∩T)+P(H'∩T)}\\&=\frac{pv}{pv+(1-p)(1-f)}\\&=0.398\%.\end{aligned} (How did you obtain your derived value? It differs from mine.)

More information here: [The accuracy of a medical test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3971235/21813).